# Timer not showing card on Android Wear

Tags: clock, android-wear

Some time ago the native count down timer app used to show a card with time remaining and an ability to pause/resume the timer. This card couldnt be dismissed and would stay until the timer was running. Now the running timer won't display any card or time remaining. Is there any way to get this functionality back?

Answer (score 0):

This appeared (to me at least) to be introduced when I installed v5.0.1 of android (on to my LG G watch). As soon as the timer is set the card usually, but not always, disappears and even more unhelpfully, on occasion, the timer no longer appears to work! This unreliability has meant that I have had to stop using it.